# Restructure multidimensional array in PHP to wanted JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to restructure a multidimensional array but i can't manage it. I'm not very good with array's... So I would like to request your assistance please !

Here is my actual array :

```
$jsonArray = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [category] => Array
            (
                [label] => avr 2016
            )

        [data] => Array
            (
                [value] => 39
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [category] => Array
            (
                [label] => mai 2016
            )

        [data] => Array
            (
                [value] => 335
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [category] => Array
            (
                [label] => jun 2016
            )

        [data] => Array
            (
                [value] => 206
            )

    )

)
```

Then i use `json_encode` to combine it with AJAX :

```
echo json_encode($jsonArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

And the result is :

```
[{"category":{"label":"avr 2016"},"data":{"value":"39"}},{"category":{"label":"mai 2016"},"data":{"value":"335"}},{"category":{"label":"jun 2016"},"data":{"value":"206"}}]
```

I'm trying to use FusionCharts example from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/Pm3nf/) !

As you see i need to create structured arrays like this :

```
"category": [
                    { "label": "Jan 2012" },
                    { "label": "Feb 2012" },
                    { "label": "Mar 2012" },
                    { "label": "Apr 2012" },

"data": [
                    { "value": "27400" },
                    { "value": "29800" },
                    { "value": "25800" },
                    { "value": "26800" },
```

Then in my AJAX code i set this for the charts :

```
var apiChart = new FusionCharts({
                type: 'scrollline2d',
                renderAt: 'chart-totalAnnee',
                width: '550',
                height: '350',
                dataFormat: 'json',
                dataSource: {
                    "chart": chartProperties,
                    "categories": arrayNeedle1,
                    "dataset": arrayNeedle2
                }
            });
```

My final request is how i can make those arrays arrayNeedle1 & arrayNeedle2, please ?

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry for my poor skills in arrays !

Best regards.

Comment: Please at least make and show an attempt rather than asking us to do it for you.

Comment: Also, that second array is impossible. You can't create two elements in an array with the same key.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your answers but i updated my request, i hope you can put me in the right way :)

Comment: note that PHP has not such month names `avr`, `mai`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : i retrieve the month values from mysql databse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have multidimensional nested arrays, restructuring it in place would be overcomplicated way, instead you may create a new array with needed structure using the following approach:

```
// supposing $arr is your initial array
$new_arr = ["category" => [], "data" => []];  // base structure
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $new_arr["category"][] = ["label" => $item["category"]["label"]];
    $new_arr["data"][] = ["value" => $item["data"]["value"]];
}

echo json_encode($new_arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

The output:

```
{
    "category": [
        {
            "label": "avr 2016"
        },
        {
            "label": "mai 2016"
        },
        {
            "label": "jun 2016"
        }
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "value": "39"
        },
        {
            "value": "335"
        },
        {
            "value": "206"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much mate ! You make my day :) With your help i managed the charts !! Have a good day and thank you gain !!
PS: i don't have enough point to give you +1 sorry but i validate your reply !